# Clock grid layout

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So I am in the process of creating a clock grid layout and am just looking for some information and advice on where to go next. Basically I have created the layout but as you will see it isn't quite perfect yet. What is the best approach to correct it? Do I have to offset it using absolute positioning or is there another more suitable approach? I am also looking for a way to make the whole clock **29 cm** and then use printElement.js (I think it is) to print it out on an A3 size paper whilst allowing padding on each side to be able to cut around.
https://screenshotscdn.firefoxusercontent.com/images/114bea21-b19b-44e7-8a9c-00965d32e71e.png

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-1-7">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="col-1-7">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="col-1-7">&nbsp;</div>
            <!-- 12 -->
            <div class="col-1-7 clock-number-12"><img src="img/placeholder.png"></div>
            <div class="col-1-7">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="col-1-7">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="col-1-7">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-1-7">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="col-1-7">&nbsp;</div>
            <!-- 11 -->
            <div class="col-1-7 clock-number-11"><img src="img/placeholder.png"></div>
            <div class="col-1-7">&nbsp;</div>
            <!-- 1 -->
            <div class="col-1-7 clock-number-1"><img src="img/placeholder.png"></div>
            <div class="col-1-7">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="col-1-7">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-1-7">&nbsp;</div>
            <!-- 10 -->
            <div class="col-1-7 clock-number-10"><img src="img/placeholder.png"></div>
            <div class="col-1-7">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="col-1-7">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="col-1-7">&nbsp;</div>
            <!-- 2 -->
            <div class="col-1-7 clock-number-2"><img src="img/placeholder.png"></div>
            <div class="col-1-7">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <!-- 9 -->
            <div class="col-1-7 clock-number-9"><img src="img/placeholder.png"></div>
            <div class="col-1-7">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="col-1-7">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="col-1-7">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="col-1-7">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="col-1-7">&nbsp;</div>
            <!-- 3 -->
            <div class="col-1-7 clock-number-3"><img src="img/placeholder.png"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-1-7">&nbsp;</div>
            <!-- 8 -->
            <div class="col-1-7 clock-number-8"><img src="img/placeholder.png"></div>
            <div class="col-1-7">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="col-1-7">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="col-1-7">&nbsp;</div>
            <!-- 4 -->
            <div class="col-1-7 clock-number-4"><img src="img/placeholder.png"></div>
            <div class="col-1-7">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-1-7">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="col-1-7">&nbsp;</div>
            <!-- 7 -->
            <div class="col-1-7 clock-number-7"><img src="img/placeholder.png"></div>
            <div class="col-1-7">&nbsp;</div>
            <!-- 5 -->
            <div class="col-1-7 clock-number-5"><img src="img/placeholder.png"></div>
            <div class="col-1-7">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="col-1-7">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-1-7">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="col-1-7">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="col-1-7">&nbsp;</div>
            <!-- 6 -->
            <div class="col-1-7 clock-number-6"><img src="img/placeholder.png"></div>
            <div class="col-1-7">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="col-1-7">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="col-1-7">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.col-1-7 {
  width: 14.28571428%;
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative to adjusting row widths and negative image margins, is javascript/jquery:

```
<div id="clock"></div>

<script src="jquery.printElement.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var tx = 300; //distance from #clock == defines the clock size
    for(var i=-60; i<300; i+=30){ //-60 > 300 = to start the process from HOUR 1
        var rad = i * (Math.PI/180);
        var x = tx*Math.cos(rad);
        var y = tx*Math.sin(rad);
        $('#clock').append("<img src='img/placeholder.png' style='left:"+x+"px;top:"+y+"px'>");
    }

    $("#clock").printElement({
        printMode:'popup',
        leaveOpen:true,
        overrideElementCSS:[
            'clock.css'
        ]
    });
});
</script>
```

And something like this in clock.css:

```
#clock{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
}

img{
    width: 50px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    position: absolute;
}
```

In you actual html page you can have totally different styling, as `overrideElementCSS` overrides the css that is included in page itself.